# Clear ViewModel throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I have a **ViewModel** what is initialize by one **Activity** and shared by multiple **Fragments**, so I have an app what only exist of one **Activity**.

When I remove my current device, I also clear my **ViewModel** manually by

```
activity?.viewModelStore?.clear()
```

After this I go back to another **Fragment** and call

```
bleDeviceViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(BleDeviceViewModel::class.java)
```

the following error is thrown ->

```
Process: de.app.ilockit, PID: 2120
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered
    at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistry.registerSavedStateProvider(SavedStateRegistry.java:111)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.attachToLifecycle(SavedStateHandleController.java:50)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.create(SavedStateHandleController.java:70)
    at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:67)
    at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:84)
    at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:107)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
    at de.app.ui.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.kt:43)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2950)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:515)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2177)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2094)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1990)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Note: I use Hilt as dependency injection if it has anything to do with it

Comment: why you are calling `ViewModelStore.clear()` ? is up to `ViewModelStoreOwner`

Comment: What did you mean why I calling viewModelStore.clear() ? I call this function to clear my view model manually, because I hav some LiveData objects in there and when I want to setup a new device, the saved values from the previous device are get called in my setup Fragments.

Comment: then create viewmodel with own key then remove this key from savedStateRegistry with unregisterSavedStateProvider

Comment: Can you give me a hint, to solve this?